# generating huge amout of random numbers with python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random

I want to generate random numbers, uniformly between -1 and 1.
I know that using NumPy and generating an array of numbers is much better than generate the one by one in a for loop.
On the other hand, I want these numbers to operate with them only once, so there's no reason for storing them in an array.
My question is, what is the best solution to this, on one hand using a for loop is not time efficient, but I don't store unnecessary numbers, I generate them one by one and then I throw them. On the other hand, an array is not memory efficient, since if I want to generate 10^10 numbers, I need to create a 10^10 size array, with horrible results.
I assume the best choice is to generate small arrays (10^3 or 10^4 elements) one by one, but I want to know if there's a better solution to this problem (maybe a NumPy function that generates the numbers but creates something like an iterable that don't store all them in memory?)

Comment: If you never need to store the results, you could just have a generator function that lazily `yield`s random numbers on demand.

Comment: Is this faster than generating the random numbers one by one without any external function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using NumPy to generate blocks of numbers is best, and you want to keep operations vectorised as much as possible.

A simple benchmark shows that somewhere between 4k and 64k is a reasonable block size:

```
from timeit import Timer
import numpy as np

for xp in range(20):
    size = 2**xp
    timer = Timer(
        f'rng.uniform(-1., 1., size={size})',
        'rng = np.random.default_rng()',
        globals=globals()
    )
    n, t = timer.autorange()
    t = min([t] + timer.repeat(3, n)) / n / size
    print(f'{size:8} = {1e-6/t:6.2f}M/s')
```

gives me

```
       1 =   0.47M/s
       2 =   0.95M/s
       4 =   1.89M/s
       8 =   3.80M/s
      16 =   7.43M/s
      32 =  14.26M/s
      64 =  27.10M/s
     128 =  48.60M/s
     256 =  78.72M/s
     512 = 119.07M/s
    1024 = 158.71M/s
    2048 = 191.51M/s
    4096 = 218.71M/s
    8192 = 233.25M/s
   16384 = 241.23M/s
   32768 = 245.35M/s
   65536 = 248.75M/s
  131072 = 250.53M/s
  262144 = 252.62M/s
  524288 = 253.99M/s
```

and working with numbers in a vectorised form is orders-of-magnitude faster.
For example, given a 64k array of values, a vectorised call of `np.sum(x)` takes 17µs while the similar version going through a generator `sum(x)` takes 3.5ms, i.e. 200 times slower.  Once you've paid the price for getting the floats out into the non-vectorised Python-world going through another `yield from` doesn't make much difference, only taking 4.5ms, e.g.: via the iPython `%timeit` magic:

```
def yield_from(it):
    yield from it

x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=2**16)

%timeit np.sum(x)
%timeit sum(x)
%timeit sum(yield_from(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

you could make a generator, as said in the comment by @Carcigenicate, and combine that with the speedup of generating entire arrays using a yield from expression.

this would look something like this:

```py
def random_numbers():
    while True:
        yield from np.random.random(1000) * 2 - 1
```

you can adjust the number of values generated at once to whatever you need, larger is faster but uses more memory